# Directive Inheritance in Nested Location Blocks

Tags: nginx

are the following two nginx server blocks semantically the same, or is there any difference? Does the JSON-specific configuration in the first example inherit the settings of the "/" location? Does it in the second example?

```
server {
  location / {
     # ...
     location ~* \.json$ {
          # json-specific settings
     }
  }
}

server {
  location / {
     # ...
  }
  location ~*  \.json$ {
    # json-specific settings
  }
}
```

Comment: An important side note is that regex locations can be nested inside regex locations (or prefix locations), but not the other way around: https://serverfault.com/a/627309/144798

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The inheritance of config directives in Nginx is such that directives can only be inherited from contexts higher up the configuration tree and never from contexts on the same level or lower.

So, a location block cannot inherit from another location block but a nested location block **can** inherit from the parent location block.

I stressed **can** because there are a number of different types of directives and the inheritance behaviour is a bit different for each.

1. There are Standard Type Directives which only have one value or set
   of values attached. These will simply be inherited by contexts lower
   down the config tree or replaced within that lower context by new
   values. An example is "index".
2. Array Type Directives which pass multiple separate values in an
   array. These will simply be inherited by contexts lower down the
   config tree or replaced within that lower context by new values.
   Note that you cannot add to the array. Changing part is replacing it
   all. An example is "proxy_param". So if you define proxy_param A and
   proxy_param B at the server level for instance, and then try to
   define proxy_param C in a location context, "A" and "B" would be
   wiped out (set to default values). as defining "C" has meant
   replacing the array.
3. Command Type Directives such as "try_files" are generally not
   inherited at all.

So specifically to your question, directives defined in one location block context cannot be inherited by another as in your second example.

Standard and Array type directives defined in the parent location block will be inherited by the nested location block. Command type directives defined in the parent will not be inherited in general.

Comment: `proxy_pass` also [isn't inherited by a nested location](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,243488,243488).

Comment: `uwsgi_pass` also isn't inherited.

Comment: Is there any damned reference table one can consult to know which directive is or isn't inherited ? What a pain having to come to SO then click on a link in a comment, pointing to another forum, reading who-knows stating that "proxy_pass isn't inherited"

Comment: @CyrilCHAPON If there is any body "who-knows" in the Nginx world, it is Maxim Dounin ... who happens to be one of the core developers. That said, just follow the categories in the answer. proxy_pass and similar, are "Command Type" directives which are not inherited.

Comment: does a website server context inherit from the main context?

Comment: @FernandoGabrielli. Yes it does. Read the first paragraph of the answer again.

Comment: Seems like a pretty serious flaw that e.g. `add_header` in child context can't include headers from the parent context. That's a serious gotcha, and one that is very non-intuitive, and will lead to duplicated lines of config.

Comment: With so many odd quirks and flaws, I struggle to understand why nginx is so popular. I'm starting to think I should have gone with ATS or something else for my reverse proxy.