# Why not always inherit add_header directives (rationale)?

Tags: nginx

What was (could be) the rationale behind Nginx's decision to only inherit `add_header` statements from the lowest level that has any?

For instance:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root my/root;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate         my.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key     my.key;

    add_header  Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload" always;
    add_header  X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header  X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header  Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https:;

    location ~* \.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|js|ico|txt)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=86400";
    }
}
```

None of those security-related headers are added to the assets which match the `location` block, dedicated to increasing cache time, just because it adds another header.

The fix would be to duplicate all `add_header` directives into the block which seems counter intuitive to how the rest of Nginx works, e.g. the `root` directive.

The behaviour is documented here:

> There could be several add_header directives. These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header

I guess there is a good explanation and I'm curious about what it is.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I just stumbled across your question when I was about to ask the exact same thing. I'm using it for almost the exact same setup.

Comment: @orokusaki, I'm afraid not.

Comment: Maybe the motivation was that it should be consistent with other array-type directives. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32126596 . A solution could be to [include](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) `add_header` lines where needed.

Comment: [Martin Fjordvald: Understanding the Nginx Configuration Inheritance Model (archived)](https://archive.is/mE8du). [original](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2012/08/understanding-the-nginx-configuration-inheritance-model/)

Comment: I reckon because it'll be much harder to "remove" certain inherited headers...
Also, I suggest using a separate `.conf` file and including that if you have too many repetitive headers.

Answer (score 1):

understood - nginx is not inheriting add_header directives -> my solution is separate config file included in every location... and not defining add_header in server level.