# nginx - add module for specific location using inheritance

Tags: nginx

I want to increase the `client_max_body_size` parameter for a specific location.

I tried to do something like that in the `location`

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://dashboard-app;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    location /admin/upload {
        client_max_body_size 10m;
    }
}
```

the problem is that there is no `proxy_pass` or all other modules in the `/admin/upload` location, so I'm gettings `404` for that route.

I know I can just add all the modules inside that location, but it's just a duplication of code which seemds useless to me.

How can I inherit the base location modules to the upload location conf?

Comment: have to duplicate either `include` the same config

Comment: Given the example in your question, only [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) and `client_max_body_size` needs to be in the new `location` - the other statements will be inherited. But the [`include` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) is also available to offload large chunks of repetitive statements.

Comment: @RichardSmith why would the other modules be inherited but the `proxy_pass` won't? where can I see which modules are inherited and which are not?

Comment: See the references in my comment and particularly note the "context".

Answer (score 2):

### Which modules are inherited and which are not?

This issue is not expressed clear in the documentation. You need to check each and every directive individually.

In general, *commands* are not inherited, *options* are inherited, *arrays of options* ("array-type directives") are inherited but replaced at whole (for example, no way to [add header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) in a descender, all headers will be replaced).

See: [Directive Inheritance in Nested Location Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104731/directive-inheritance-in-nested-location-blocks#answer-32126596) answer.

### How to avoid code duplication?

From **nginx** side only [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive can be used for that.
Also, a [recommended way](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/variables_in_config.html) is to use third party tools (e.g. template engines) to generate nginx config from a concise source.